# herenow api has been rolled out. Is there any way to get the checkedin userdetail?

Tags: foursquare

We have integrated hereNow api in our appliction to show the checked in customers for the particular venue. Now because of the policy change in the hereNow api we are not getting any results. Is there any way to get the checkedin user details for the venue without being as a store manager?

Thanks,
Shiva

Answer (score 0):

No. The identities of users currently checked in to a venue are only available to apps making requests on the behalf of friends, other people checked in to the venue, or to a manager of the venue.

Comment: won't that encourage developers to create _fake_ checkins just so to be able to obtain the identities of users currently checked in to any given venue (and thus skew the venue checkinsCount stat along with wrecking other havok) ?

Comment: Fake check-ins are against our house rules and are very much grounds for app/account suspension: https://foursquare.com/info/houserules